# How do i filter an array inside of a array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to filter a list by **tags**:

```
const initialState = [
     {id:1 ,name: 'Product A', image: 'pic-001.jpg', tags: ['nature', 'camping', 'outdoor']},
     {id:2 ,name: 'Product B', image: 'pic-002.jpg', tags: ['winter', 'hiking', 'camping', 'snow']},
     {id:3 ,name: 'Product C', image: 'pic-003.jpg', tags: ['vacation', 'family', 'kids', 'river', 'lake', 'fishing']}
   ]
```

I can filter the list by **name** using `map` and `filter`, my problem is when i try to list the products by tags. Do i have to use `foreach` inside of my products filter? There's another way of doing it?

Comment: I don't think there is any other way of doing it. You will have to iterate through the array for your condition of matching with tags.

Comment: you could just use array.indexOf in your filter function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like that?

```
const filter = 'nature';
const filteredResult = initialState.filter((item) => {
    return (item.tags.indexOf(filter) >= 0);
});
```

Comment: Why not use `includes`?

Comment: @destoryer what's `includes`? It may be a feature from lodash or underscore, but I think it's not native JS.

Comment: [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) not supported by IE though.

Comment: That's nice to know about, I thought it was from an utility lib! Nice :)

Comment: some how i had to convert to string for it to work. Otherwise it was buggy, not sure why. `return (item.tags.toString().indexOf(tag) >= 0);`. Thanks guys, and sorry for the late reply!

Answer (score 9):

You can create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of selected tags, and use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if at least one of the tags in the Set exists in the objects' tags list:

```js
const initialState = [
     {id:1 ,name: 'Product A', image: 'pic-001.jpg', tags: ['nature', 'camping', 'outdoor']},
     {id:2 ,name: 'Product B', image: 'pic-002.jpg', tags: ['winter', 'hiking', 'camping', 'snow']},
     {id:3 ,name: 'Product C', image: 'pic-003.jpg', tags: ['vacation', 'family', 'kids', 'river', 'lake', 'fishing']}
];

const filterByTags = ['nature', 'family'];

const filterByTagSet = new Set(filterByTags);

const result = initialState.filter((o) => 
  o.tags.some((tag) => filterByTagSet.has(tag))
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just what I needed

Answer (score 1):

you can use indexOf function

```
var foo = initialState.filter(function(elm){
  return elm.tags.indexOf("camping")>=0
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly to get all the tags and filter the duplicate tags from initialState. Save the array into uniqueTags.

Then compare the uniqueTags with initialState names, to create another array productTags with objects and its properties tags and products.

```
const initialState = [
     {id:1 ,name: 'Product A', image: 'pic-001.jpg', tags: ['nature', 'camping', 'winter', 'outdoor']},
     {id:2 ,name: 'Product B', image: 'pic-002.jpg', tags: ['winter', 'hiking', 'family', 'camping', 'snow']},
     {id:3 ,name: 'Product C', image: 'pic-003.jpg', tags: ['vacation', 'family', 'kids', 'river', 'lake', 'fishing']}
   ]

   let allTags = [];
   initialState.map((t)=>t.tags).forEach((a)=>a.forEach((b)=>allTags.push(b)))
   let uniqueTags = allTags.filter((a,i,arr)=>arr.indexOf(a,i+1)===-1)


   productTags = [];
   uniqueTags.forEach((u)=>{
       initialState.forEach((t)=>{
           if(t.tags.includes(u))
            productTags.push({'tag': u, 'product':t.name});
       })
   })


   console.log(JSON.stringify(productTags));

   /*
   [
    { "tag": "nature", "product": "Product A" }, 
    { "tag": "outdoor", "product": "Product A" }, 
    { "tag": "winter", "product": "Product A" }, 
    { "tag": "winter", "product": "Product B" }, 
    { "tag": "hiking", "product": "Product B" }, 
    { "tag": "camping", "product": "Product A" }, 
    { "tag": "camping", "product": "Product B" }, 
    { "tag": "snow", "product": "Product B" }, 
    { "tag": "vacation", "product": "Product C" }, 
    { "tag": "family", "product": "Product B" }, 
    { "tag": "family", "product": "Product C" }, 
    { "tag": "kids", "product": "Product C" }, 
    { "tag": "river", "product": "Product C" }, 
    { "tag": "lake", "product": "Product C" }, 
    { "tag": "fishing", "product": "Product C" }
] */
```

## (Edited later) Correction:

To form the correct object, I have changed the code to:

```
const initialState = [
     {id:1 ,name: 'Product A', image: 'pic-001.jpg', tags: ['nature', 'camping', 'winter', 'outdoor']},
     {id:2 ,name: 'Product B', image: 'pic-002.jpg', tags: ['winter', 'hiking', 'family', 'camping', 'snow']},
     {id:3 ,name: 'Product C', image: 'pic-003.jpg', tags: ['vacation', 'family', 'kids', 'river', 'lake', 'fishing']}
   ]

   let allTags = [];
   initialState.map((t)=>t.tags).forEach((a)=>a.forEach((b)=>allTags.push(b)))
   let uniqueTags = allTags.filter((a,i,arr)=>!arr.includes(a,i+1))


   productTags = [];
   uniqueTags.forEach((u)=>{
       let productName = [];
       initialState.forEach((t)=>{
           if(t.tags.includes(u))
            productName.push(t.name);
       })
       productTags.push({tag:u, products:productName}); 
   })

   console.log(JSON.stringify(productTags));

   /*
    productTags = [
        {"tag":"nature","products":["Product A"]},
        {"tag":"outdoor","products":["Product A"]},
        {"tag":"winter","products":["Product A","Product B"]},
        {"tag":"hiking","products":["Product B"]},
        {"tag":"camping","products":["Product A","Product B"]},
        {"tag":"snow","products":["Product B"]},
        {"tag":"vacation","products":["Product C"]},
        {"tag":"family","products":["Product B","Product C"]},
        {"tag":"kids","products":["Product C"]},
        {"tag":"river","products":["Product C"]},
        {"tag":"lake","products":["Product C"]},
        {"tag":"fishing","products":["Product C"]}
    ] 
    */
```