# return value after filtering array inside an object of arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I am trying to create an autocomplete which returns an array of objects using a function. My Object is something like:

```
this.vehiclesList =
  [
    {
      "additionalDriverContacts": [9929929929, 9992992933, 9873773777],
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "additionalDriverContacts": [8388388388, 8939939999],
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
```

I want to filter the array based on **additionalDriverContacts** .

My function goes like this:

```
filterVehicleAdditionalMobile(val: string) {
     if (typeof val != 'string') {
            return [];
        }
    let value= val? this.vehiclesList.filter((item) => {
            if(item.additionalDriverContacts) 
                 item.additionalDriverContacts.forEach((option)=> {
                   String(option).toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1 
                })
             }
     }) : this.vehiclesList;
    console.log(value)
    return value;
}
```

But in the console value is coming empty array. Where did I go wrong. I tried looking for the solution in this question [How do i filter an array inside of a array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44949792/how-do-i-filter-an-array-inside-of-a-array-of-objects)
but it didnot help as my usecase is different.

**My desired Result should be like:** 
If 99299 is passed as an argument to the function , then additionalDriverContacts matching that number should be return as an array. 
for input 99299, result = [9929929929,9992992933] should be returned

Comment: Note you initially have `this.vehicleList` but your code later uses `: this.vehiclesList` - extra `s`. Also, your `String(option)..` line is an orphaned expression.

Comment: There's no JSON anywhere in your code. It's a JavaScript object. And I will keep pointing this out until the day I die.

Comment: Thank you for showing the mistake . I updated it

Comment: @ChrisG edited. Thanx

Comment: That long `String` line you have there is simply an expression, it doesn't actually do anything. Since you're calling `filter()`, I'm guessing you'll want to `return` it.

Comment: @ChrisG Actually my array elements are number and user input is string. So I thought it might be imp to convert to string

Comment: @ChrisG if I dont put that String line , I wasn't getting the result. I wanted to match the user defined value which is the argument of the function , with the array values. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your filter doesnt return anything, so everything is concidered false and then you get nothing :)

Comment: @xrobert35 Ya that I realised from the console that filter isn't returning anything. How do I correct it

Comment: You must keep only items that are in additionalDriverContacts last , right ?

Comment: @xrobert35 Ya thats true. Only items of additionalDriverContacts which are matching the user input

Comment: You need to explain what the desired result is, so that means people need to try to guess based on your failed attempt. Please add that information to your question.

Comment: @UdG "How do I correct it" Just `return` true or false from the function. https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/gmhqswvy/

Comment: @JLRishe edited

Comment: Didn't got the reason of downvote

Answer (score 1):

> for input `99299`, result = `[9929929929,9992992933]` should be returned

We can use array `.map()` to extract contacts, then filter down with string `.search()`:

```js
const vehiclesList = [
    {"id": 1, "additionalDriverContacts": [9929929929, 9992992933, 9873773777]},
    {"id": 2, "additionalDriverContacts": [8388388388, 8939939999]}]

result = getMatchingContacts(vehiclesList, 99299) // run test
console.log(result)                               // show result

function getMatchingContacts(list, key) {  
  const arrayOfContacts = list.map(item => item.additionalDriverContacts)
  const contacts = [].concat(...arrayOfContacts)                       // flatten the nested array
    .filter(contact => contact.toString().search(key.toString()) >= 0) // find matches
  return contacts
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Updated : With the last edit of the question

try to change by :

```
  filterVehicleAdditionalMobile(val: string) {
    if (typeof val !== 'string') {
      return [];
    }

    let driverContacts = [];
    this.vehiclesList.forEach((vehicule) => {
      if (vehicule.additionalDriverContacts) {
        if (val) {
          driverContacts = driverContacts.concat(vehicule.additionalDriverContacts.filter((driverContact) => {
            return String(driverContact).toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
          }));
        } else {
          driverContacts = driverContacts.concat(vehicule.additionalDriverContacts);
        }
      }
    });

    return driverContacts;
  }
```

Test :

```
const driver = this.filterVehicleAdditionalMobile('8');
console.log(driver);
```

Display :

0: 9873773777
1: 8388388388
2: 8939939999

Comment: Your solution is returning the list of all the array items not the particular matching array item. Also few syntax errors.

Comment: I kept the logic of your code, since your don't use "val" in your filter it will result in something like that

Comment: you want to keep the vehicule where the **val** match one of the additionnalDriverContacts ?

Comment: all the matched values should come inside an array

Comment: @UdG Have you had a look at my answer?

Comment: Yes I am trying

Comment: So you want to contactDriver list not the  vehicule list ?

Comment: Its returning the whole object value that's matching. How do I return just the array which is matching

Comment: You want the list of all the additionalDriverContacts from all vehicule matching the "val" ? If I give "8" you want 3 resultats since 8 is contains by 3 additionalDriverContacts  [9873773777,  8388388388, 8939939999]

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do here is first transform each of the items in `vehiclesList` into an array of matching results, and then concatenate those together.

Give this a try:

```js
var vehiclesList = [{
    "additionalDriverContacts": [9929929929, 9992992933, 9873773777],
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "additionalDriverContacts": [8388388388, 8939939999],
    "id": 2
  }
];

function filterVehicleAdditionalMobile(val) {
  if (typeof val != 'string') {
    return [];
  }
  // array of arrays
  const values = vehiclesList.map((item) => {
      if (!item.additionalDriverContacts) { return []; }
      
      return item.additionalDriverContacts.filter((option) => 
          String(option).toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1
      );
  });
  
  console.log(values);

  // flatten
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], values);
}

console.log(filterVehicleAdditionalMobile('99'));
```

Alternatively, you could concatenate all of the items together and then filter them. This is less efficient, but simpler and less code:

```js
var vehiclesList = [{
    "additionalDriverContacts": [9929929929, 9992992933, 9873773777],
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "additionalDriverContacts": [8388388388, 8939939999],
    "id": 2
  }
];

function flatten(values) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], values);
}

function filterVehicleAdditionalMobile(val) {
  if (typeof val != 'string') {
    return [];
  }
  
  return flatten(vehiclesList.map(v => v.additionalDriverContacts || []))
      .filter(option => String(option).toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1);
}

console.log(filterVehicleAdditionalMobile('99'));
```

Comment: No its not working. while consoling , its showing arrays inside array if matches

Comment: @UdG Both of the above result in a single array, as seen when you click the Run code snippet button. In the first example, I am logging the `values` variable before I concatenate the values together, so remember to scroll down to see the final value. Or are you saying it doesn't produce the desired result when you adapt it to your own code?